# Write a function where the output for both "sum(2,3)" and "sum(2)(3)" will be 5

Tags: javascript

Recently I come up with a question in an interview which is "write a function which will output of these two will same sum(2,3) and sum(2)(3), that is 5".

Please give any idea if it is possible.

Thanks in advance

Comment: sum(2)(3)... is not possible

Comment: @Rakin It is possible in JavaScript. The code `result = sum(2)(3)` is effectively the same as `f = sum(2); result = f(3)`, without the intermediate variable. This is because JavaScript functions are themselves just (first-class) values.

Comment: great..new information thank you @user2864740

Answer (score 3):

For `sum(x)(y)`, have `sum(x)` return another function, f, such that `f(y)` - ie. `(sum(x))(y)` - evaluates to the correct result. See [Eloquent JavaScript: Higher-Order Functions](http://eloquentjavascript.net/05_higher_order.html) for examples on how closures - and returning functions from functions - make this possible.

The [`arguments.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/length) property can be used to determine how many arguments have been supplied to the (`sum`) function and react accordingly: either the immediate sum, for `sum(x, y)`, or the aforementioned ['curried' function](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/www_svendtofte_com/code/curried_javascript/index.html) when invoked with a singular argument.

(The linked "Curried JavaScript functions: no, not curried spicy, but curried lambda-calculus-like" article actually contains a solution in full.. but it feels that to provide the code here would be cheating.)

Comment: I don't think it would be "cheating", rather it would be helpful as the link may not exist forever (simply give credit when you include the code). Also people are lazy and may not want to go to another webpage and look for it.

Answer (score 3):

Here's your simple function without counting the args:

```
function sum(a,b){
    if(b===undefined){
        return function(c){ return parseInt(a)+parseInt(c);}
    }
    return parseInt(a)+parseInt(b);
}
console.log(sum(2,3));
console.log(sum(2)(3));
```

Comment: `b=''` isn't going to work in some browsers (*Chrome*).